Linux -Debian 12 virtual OS. while installing pip3 requirements for python packages I got this error in my Debian terminal.?
I was installing this directory brute forcing tool dirsearch git clone https://github.com/maurosoria/dirsearch.git --depth 1. in my debian 12 linux virtual OS. while Installing pip3 install dirsearch. I encountered following error in my terminal.
 WARNING: The script normalizer is installed in '/home/david/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
 Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
 WARNING: The script pyspnego-parse is installed in '/home/david/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
 Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed Jinja2-3.1.4 PySocks-1.7.1 beautifulsoup4-4.12.3 cffi-1.17.0 charset_normalizer-2.0.12 colorama-0.4.6 cryptography-43.0.0 defusedxml-0.7.1 mysql-connector-python-9.0.0 ntlm_auth-1.5.0 psycopg-3.2.1 psycopg-binary-3.2.1 pycparser-2.22 pyopenssl-24.2.1 pyspnego-0.11.1 requests-toolbelt-1.0.0 requests_ntlm-1.3.0 soupsieve-2.6 typing-extensions-4.12.2
david@debian:~/dirsearch$ cd dirsearch```.


There’s no error there, just two warnings. What is your question? Have you tried doing what the warning suggests?

no, I didn't. tell me how can I do those warnings ? I mean it says the script normalizer is installed in '/home/david/.local/bin which is not on PATH, consider adding this directory to PATH ?tell me how to add it.

hello Stephen kitt could you please respond !!

See the answers to the linked question, How to correctly add a path to PATH?
